# How to convert a byte array to an image?

Tags: c#

I tried to convert a `byte` array to an image but nothing and no error.

```
byte[] data = user.Properties["thumbnailPhoto"].Value as byte[];
if (data != null)
{
    using (MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream(data))
    {
          Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(s);
          imbThumbnail.ImageUrl = bmp.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not how URLs work.  You need an HTTP endpoint, or a `data:` URI.

Comment: bmp.ToString() (rather, [Object.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx)) does not provide an URL as you seem to believe...

Comment: Try `imbThumbnail.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64,"+ Convert.ToBase64String(data);`

Comment: What is the type of the object imbThumbnail ?

Comment: @L.B thanks it worked well , please add your answer to vote your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `Bitmap` class. All you need is base64 encoded data as below

```
imbThumbnail.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64,"+ Convert.ToBase64String(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
     MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
     Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
     return returnImage;
}
```

Source : [C# Image to Byte Array and Byte Array to Image Converter Class](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15460/C-Image-to-Byte-Array-and-Byte-Array-to-Image-Conv)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
var image = Image.FromStream(stream);
```